# How to create profile in Gnome Terminal programmatically (from command line)

Tags: opensuse, gnome-terminal

I want to configure Gnome Terminal using a non-interactive script. I know how to configure an *existing* profile, but that requires the profile ID:

```
# List the UUIDs
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList list

# Set palette colors, for instance:
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:<profile ID> [<list of palette colors>]
```

But how to *create* a terminal profile from command line?

On a more general note, where is all this stuff documented? `man gsettings` tells very little. For instance, if the schema name contains the word 'legacy', what is the 'contemporary' way to do the same? Or where does, for instance, `/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles` come from? I found it in a blog article, but there should be some documentation somewhere, shouldn't it?

I'm using OpenSuse Leap 15.2

Comment: This looks promising: [CentOS 6.8 – Script adding a new gnome\-terminal profile](https://blogs.czapski.id.au/2016/11/centos-6-8-script-adding-a-new-gnome-terminal-profile)

Answer (score 2):

GSettings is an abstract interface over some platform-specific settings storage API, for example, Registry on Windows or dconf on Linux. GSettings enforces strong typing and schema compliance while the underlying dconf only stores keys/values without any checking.

Usually, each GSettings schema has only one instance and the schema name directly maps to a single dconf location – `org.gnome.Foo` is stored as a folder `/org/gnome/Foo` in dconf. (Though the schema can override this, hence the mismatch between `/terminal` and `.Terminal`.)

```
dconf dump /org/gnome
```

But GNOME Terminal needs multiple instances, so it uses a feature called "relocatable schemas" where the dconf storage path is specified explicitly instead of being automatically determined from the schema XML description. (This is somewhat of an ugly way to implement it, but that's how it is.)

I am not sure where the weird path syntax is described (if anywhere at all), but it very much seems that everything after the first colon is just a single long dconf path – there doesn't seem to be any meaning to the `:/:foo` and those colons just become part of the "folder" name. If you launch `dconf-editor` and browse the settings, you will see this hierarchy:

```
org
└─ gnome
   └─ terminal
      └─ legacy
         └─ profiles:
            └─ :<profile ID>
```

So the first thing I would try is simply to choose a new random UUID and start setting the profile parameters at that UUID using `gsettings set`.

If that fails, just directly use `dconf write` or even `dconf load` to set the same values directly within the dconf storage.

> For instance, if the schema name contains the word 'legacy', what is the 'contemporary' way to do the same?

The schema name is defined by the application (GNOME Terminal), and the specific words are not something that GSettings can have opinions about.

Apparently there were some plans to do a clean rewrite of GNOME Terminal (i.e. make a completely new UI, keeping only the vte terminal widget) around the same time as it migrated from the old GNOME 2.x "GConf" settings system to the 3.x GSettings API. So when the GSettings schema name was chosen for the old Terminal app, the word "Legacy" was added.

(The rewrite never happened.)